# Lowest value path in a binary search tree

Tags: java, tree, binary-search-tree

Was asked this in an interview recently and got stumped.

Given a binary tree where the nodes contain integer values, find the path (going all the way down to the leaves) that sum up to the lowest value.

So starting at root and traversing all the way down in a depth first fashion until you get to a leaf and adding up the node values along the way. Repeat for every possible path to the leaves.

I was just overwhelmed by the amount of possibilities there could be. But i tried doing a dfs, adding up values along the way, until i got to a leaf. Stored the path and the sum in a hashmap. But then I couldn't figure out how to reset the current sum and go down a different path to a different leaf the second time around.

Comment: I imagine it would involve some sort of loop, as such, what if you had a list that stored each value for every iteration of the dfs? Once it has traversed all the nodes, you can just grab the largest one. I recall having to know how to find that in my data structures class, it was in C++ and I can't quite recall now.

Comment: Just use recursive implementation and the stack will "hold" all the data you need. But going it this way you guarantee full traversal, which is sub-optimal. Using BFS traversal could halt certain paths in the middle, but that's harder to design.

Comment: The thing with dfs is it will get to the end and climb back up and find the next non-visited node. But I will need to know the sum at the node it diverges to find the next non-visited node if I'm to record it as a new path. It's hard to explain through words I guess but basically a dfs doesn't work unless some clever remembering sum at particular nodes feature is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

It could be solved along these lines: Imagine that we define the function `lowestValuePath(path, currentValue, bst)` which takes a path as a string representation ("lrlrr" would be equivalent to having gone left, right, left, right, right), a value which is the currently accumulated sum of node values along this path, and bst which is the tree to traverse.

Our starting case would be `lowestValuePath("", 0, rootNode)`, and termination would occur on a leaf, returning the path traversed and the value accumulated along this path.

Java-ish pseudo code could be:

```
TraverseResult {
  String path;
  int value;
}

TraverseResult lowestValuePath(path, currentValue, bst) {
  val newValue = currentValue + bst.getNodeValue();
  if bst.isLeaf():
    return new TraverseResult(path, newValue);
  else
    val rightPath = lowestValuePath(path + "r", newValue, bst.getRightNode());
    val leftPath = lowestValuePath(path + "l", newValue, bst.getLeftNode());
    return leftPath < rightPath ? leftPath : rightPath
}
```

Some special case handling for the empty tree might be necessary..

Answer (score 0):

If it is a "Binary Search Tree", then for every node T:
  left(T) <= T <= right(T)

So actually just turn left all the time and you will get to the lowest value.

Comment: Doesn't have to be a binary search tree.